# Spring Boot application is running on Redhat Enterprise Linux server using Docker container and want to access the application on windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

Spring Boot application is running on Redhat Enterprise Linux server using Docker container and want to access the application on Windows.

When I run the command `docker ps`, got below details.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
fccfd256180d        test:latest         "java -jar Student.j…"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours         0.0.0.0:8090->8090/tcp   vigilant_poitras
```

I tested application on server using command:

```
curl http://localhost:8090/student
```

I am getting the response on server. But not able to access on Windows.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but try: `docker exec -it <container-name> sh`

Comment: I am trying to test the application on Windows10 OS. I am able to access the Linux server using putty and on the server Docker is installed. Application is running on Docker container , I tested there also. But I am not able to access on Windows10 OS. I hope scenario will be more clear now :)

Comment: I assume the docker container is running in the private network and has a private IP. It is impossible to access it from outside without having some forwarding/hosting stuff done - I guess!